# How do I add blank rows after each item from a FILTER() or QUERY() result?

Tags: google-sheets

Suppose you have a spreadsheet similar to:

```
            A
1   "text a1"
2   "text a2"
3   "text a3"
4   "text a4"
```

...and you'd like to create a new column containing each item followed by two blank rows, such as:

```
            A          B          C
1   "text a1"  "text a1" 
2   "text a2"
3   "text a3"
4   "text a4"  "text a2"
6
7
8              "text a3"
9
10
11             "text a4"
12
13
```

How can you do that?

Answer (score 5):

After playing around a bit, I landed on the following:

1. Appending each row with a string containing a delimiter with `JOIN()`, then
2. Splitting them with `SPLIT()` and
3. Converting the resulting array into a column with `TRANSPOSE()`

Like this:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ArrayFormula(JOIN(" , , ,",FILTER(A:A, A:A <> ""))),","))
```

Comment: This works as long as the column you're working with does not contain commas. Something more exotic, like a Unicode character above code 257, would be safer. I tend to use ✏ because it's `char(9999)`...

Comment: Works!!!!.............

Answer (score -1):

How I use this... Throw this in script editor.  Create a drawing (I use a the 'button' shape) and label it addRows or something.  Then save and close the drawing box.  Right click on the button and then click the drop down arrow in the top right hand corner.  Click assign script.  Then just write "addRows" without arguments or quotation marks.

```
function addRows(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();

  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows*2 - 1; i+=2) {
    sheet.insertRowAfter(i);
  }
}
```

You could also create a custom menu option instead of the button with something like this...

> function onOpen() {
>
> > var menu = [{name: "Add rows to current sheet", functionName: "addRows"}];
> >
> > SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Custom", menu);
>
> }

Hope that helps

Comment: added some instructions